# Ngrx selector not triggering when the reducer alters the slice

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am working on an angular 2 application that uses Ngrx stores extensively. I got a  decent structure in my stores. I use selectors to retrieve slices of state and usually all the selectors properly triggers their associated subscriptions. Ngrx is amazing.

Sadly, today I walked into a new issue and I tried looking around on the web for solutions without success. I finally found a work-around myself by testing out different syntax but I am curious as to why this is happening.

This selector is exactly like all my other selectors:

```
export const getToolBars = (state: State): any => state.toolBars;
export const selectState: MemoizedSelector<object, State> = createFeatureSelector<State>('http');
export const selectToolBars: MemoizedSelector<object, any> = createSelector(selectState, getToolBars);
```

The problem is that the selector does not trigger the subscription like it should when the data is updated via the reducer.

I found a work-around for this particular case. Using this :

```
export const getToolBars = (state: State): any => { return { toolBars: state.toolBars }; };
```

Instead of :

```
export const getToolBars = (state: State): any => state.toolBars;
```

fixes it but I would prefer to have all my getters look the same so I wonder why is this issue happening in the first place?

Additional informations, the state.toolBars is an object interfaced as

```
toolBars: { [name: string]: any };
```

Any hints or references would do. Right now everything "works" I am only looking for ways to improve my skill set. Thank you very much!

**Edit:**

I made a stackblitz to illustrate the issue.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-selector-issue?file=src%2Fapp%2Froot-store%2Ftest-store%2Fselectors.ts

On this stackblitz, i made log to console for whenever stuff is being added in the toolBars state by the reducer. Every two seconds, a new entry is being added to the state.

In the current state, the subscription is not triggering when the reducer add content.

If in the selectors.ts we comment line 6 and uncomment line 7, it works as it does in my application. And I am wondering why usual syntax wont...

Comment: Everything seems fine to me tho. Do you have a complete example?

Comment: Sadly, this is part of a huge app and I cannot provide it but I will try to put together a stackblitz with the full setup.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that `state.toolBars` isn't being modified, thus not resulting in a "selector call".

Comment: There we go: 

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-selector-issue?file=src%2Fapp%2Froot-store%2Ftest-store%2Fselectors.ts

On this stackblitz, i made log to console for whenever stuff is being added in the toolBars state by the reducer. Every two seconds, a new entry is being added to the state.

In the current state, the subscription is not triggering when the reducer add content.

If in the selectors.ts we comment line 6 and uncomment line 7, it works as it does in my application. And I am wondering why usual syntax wont...

Comment: @timdeschryver That is what I was thinking in the first place and that's where I added a log inside the reducer to make sure, and it was effectively going by there. Also, I strongly believe the state IS modified, otherwise my workaround would not work!?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are modifying the state directly, this is the problem.

Selectors are memoized by default and check if the arguments are changed between the last call and the current call. This check is a simple reference check (`===`). Because you're modifying the state directly, the reference stays the same.

To fix this you can do:

```
return {
        ...state,
        toolBars: {
          ...state.toolBars,
          [action.value]: action.subValue
        }
}
```

You can also use [ngrx-immer](https://github.com/timdeschryver/ngrx-immer) which takes care of this for you.

Comment: I just tried it and it does work. Thank you very much for your help!

Have a very good day :)

Comment: Glad we got it sorted out :)