# Array subscription gets triggered when other parts of the state change in NgRx

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have `locations` and `activeLocationsIds` array. `locations` array contains all locations, `activeLocationsIds` contains IDs from active locations (not objects, only IDs that are 1..1 with `locations` IDs).

Anytime other parts of the state get changed, e.g., selectedOrder, the subscription for `activeLocationsIds` gets triggered.

This is my state:

```
export interface ICustomerHierarchyState {
    locations: ILocation[],
    activeLocationsIds: string[];
    selectedOrder: number;
}
```

These are selectors for fetching activeLocations:

```
export const getActiveLocationsIds = createSelector(
    getCustomerHierarchyState,
    state => state.activeLocationsIds
)

export const getActiveLocations = createSelector(
    getCustomerHierarchyState,
    getActiveLocationsIds ,
    (state, getActiveLocationsIds ) => state.locations.filter(x => getActiveLocationsIds.includes(x.locationId)) ?? []
)
```

This is the activeLocationsIds reducer:

```
on(CustomerHierarchyPageActions.setActiveLocations, (state, action): ICustomerHierarchyState => {
        return {
            ...state,
            activeLocationsIds: action.locationsIds
        }
    })
```

This is the `activeLocationsIds` action:

```
export const setActiveLocations = createAction(
    '[Customer-Hierarchy Page] Set ActiveLocations',
    props<{ locationsIds: string[] }>()
)
```

Also, here is the reducer for clearing `selectedOrder`:

```
on(CustomerHierarchyPageActions.clearSelectedOrder, (state): ICustomerHierarchyState => {
        return {
            ...state,
            selectedOrder: -1
        }
    })
```

Finally, this is `getActiveLocations` subscription:

```
this.subscriptions.add(
      this.store.select(getActiveLocations)
        .subscribe(
          activeLocations => {
            this.activeLocations = activeLocations;
          }
        ));
```

Anytime I dispatch a different action for example `this.store.dispatch(CustomerHierarchyPageActions.clearSelectedOrder());`, subscription for the `activeLocations` gets triggered.

Why is that?

In my reducer, I only update `selectedOrder` (to -1 value) so I don't know why `getActiveLocations` subscription gets triggered...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your answer: [Ngrx selector not triggering when the reducer alters the slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53089707/ngrx-selector-not-triggering-when-the-reducer-alters-the-slice)

> This check is a simple reference check (===). Because you're modifying
> the state directly, the reference stays the same

You are creating a new object, this means a new reference

**UPDATE:**

The easiest solution for you would be to use distinctuntilchanged operator with custom comparer (https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged)

Comment: Can you please help me.
I don't know how to implement this to my implementation...
Can I implement this without ngrx-immer?

Comment: @DomagojHamzic the easiest solution for you would be to use `distinctuntilchanged` operator with custom comparer (https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged). If you need a help with that, please create a small app that reproduces your problem on stackblitz.com or plnkr.co

Comment: distinctuntilchanged solves the problem. Please add this comment as an answer so I can accept it as an answer.

Comment: @DomagojHamzic glad that it helped! I've updated the answer, so it contains all info

Answer (score -1):

It might be related to the way you are assigning the action payload directly to `activeLocationIds` in the reducer - you should make a copy instead:

```
on(CustomerHierarchyPageActions.setActiveLocations, (state, action): ICustomerHierarchyState => {
  return {
    ...state,
    activeLocationsIds: [...action.locationsIds]
  }
})
```